# How to write a regexp, that matches parts of a string that either start or end with something specific

Tags: regex

Consider the following strings:

> hotpoint nm11 823 wk eu n **1200 rpm** 8 kg class a+++
> hotpoint nm11 823 wk eu n **rpm 1200** 8 kg class a+++
> hotpoint nm11 823 wk eu n **rpm1200** 8 kg class a+++

How could I write a regexp, that will match the highlighted part in either string? Basically, I want a regexp that will match part of a string that either starts with `rpm` or ends with `rpm` and contains only spaces and numbers in between.

To do a regexp that starts with `rpm` and contains only numbers or spaces, I could do something like this:

`/((rpm)\s{0,1}(\d+))/`

and I also know that I can achieve the desired result by adding an additional `| (OR)` part to the regexp by this:

`/((rpm)\s{0,1}(\d+)|(\d+)\s{0,1}rpm)/`

What I am interested in, if there is any other way to specify that the matched part should either start or end with something specific, without duplicating the whole matching rule?

**Note**, that the part of the string I am looking for is not on the end or the beginning of the string, so I can't use `$` or `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some regex flavors, including PCRE and PyPi in Python, if you put a capture group around the pattern, you can match the pattern again elsewhere with `(?1)` syntax, with the `1` replaced with the capture group index, like this:

```
(rpm)\s?\d+|\d+\s?(?1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/neK7cC/1

Note that `{0,1}` simplifies to `?`.

If one isn't lucky enough to be working with an engine that supports recursing subpatterns, one will have to repeat the pattern again, or find out another way.

Comment: as for the operation I am trying to perform, speed is rather important, would this result in a porential speed increase for the regular expression, or it will only be visualizible better by a human person?

Comment: It will depend on the environment the RE is running in and the text that's being examined. The difference may get compiled away, but it might not - run a performance test with the different patterns to find out.